# How to call multiple functions by using hc-05 bluetooth module?

Tags: function, arduino, bluetooth, strip, led

I am really new here. I am making an LED project using Arduino uno, WS28128B, HC-05 module. 
 Also using Fastled library. 
So I want to create 3 or 4 functions which should be my led effects And whenever I press button in my phone that specific function will run.

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is break down your project into different parts.

Your project is basically a chain: `phone->HC-05->Arduino->WS2812B` . So you can easily divide it into parts:

1. Writing the RGB value to WS2812B. You can install an Arduino library for this LED. You can simply run the example code from the library to test your LED.
2. Writing your effects. Write functions that write different RGB values to the LED with some delays. You can test it by calling them directly in loop().
3. Write the bluetooth part. All you need to do is send one byte from your phone to the Arduino. For instance 0x01 or 0x31 ('1') for function 1.
   You can find many tutorials online for the bluetooth part. Example: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Setting_up_Bluetooth_HC-05_with_Arduino
4. Connect the bluetooth part to the effects. You can use switch-case to use the received byte to call the desired effect.